# Eigenvalues of a Self-Adjoint Operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

It is easy to see that eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of a self-adjoint operator $T$ are mutually orthogonal. However, from this, it is supposed to be easy to see that for a given positive number $\delta$ there are only finitely many eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $T$ such that $|\lambda| \geq \delta$.

How can I easily see this?